# How To Make Destination of Android Navigation Component Inflated in Different Destinations Not Be Edited as If They Were Shared Instances?

Tags: kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

**SCENARIO:**

I use **BottomNavigationView** component on my app setup with **Android Navigation Component**. It's a Social Network app with *Home*, *Feed*, *Challenges*, *Map* and *Profile* as main destinations of the app. There are 2 destinations (***destination_feed*** and ***destination_profile***) that use a third destination (***navigation_graph_posts***) inside them. The picture below shows more or less the scenario:

[image: Android Navigation Component Scenario]

**PROBLEM:**

When I access ***destination_profile*** (which shows only posts of logged in user) and go back to ***destination_feed***, the posts shown on ***destination_feed*** (that previously were all posts) now only show the same posts shown on ***destination_profile***. It looks like the changes I do on posts from ***profile_destination*** are reflected on the posts from ***feed_destination***.

I think that the problem is that by default, Android Navigation Component inflate navgraph destinations with option **launchSingleTop** as **TRUE** but I couldn't find how to change it to **FALSE** because the ***destination_posts*** is the **StartDestination** of ***Posts_navigation_graph*** and ***Posts_navigation_graph*** is programmatically inflated inside ***destination_feed*** and ***destination_profile***. Below the code I am using (reduced to the parts that matters):

feed_navigation.xml

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/feed_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/destination_feed">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_feed"
        android:name="com.jonathan.maxplore.screen.feed.view.FeedFragment"
        android:label="@string/fragment_label_feed"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed">
        <argument
            android:name="showBottomNavigation"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

profile_navigation.xml

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/destination_profile">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_profile"
        android:name="com.jonathan.maxplore.screen.profile.view.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/fragment_label_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">
        <argument
            android:name="showBottomNavigation"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

posts_navigation.xml

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/posts_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/destination_posts">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_posts"
        android:name="com.jonathan.maxplore.screen.posts.view.PostsFragment"
        android:label="@string/fragment_label_posts"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_posts">
        <argument
            android:name="showAppBar"
            android:defaultValue="true" />

        <argument
            android:name="mode"
            app:argType="com.jonathan.maxplore.util.PostsMode"/>

        <argument
            android:name="identifier"
            android:defaultValue="0L"
            app:argType="long"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

fragment_feed.xml

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_feed_content"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

fragment_profile.xml

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_content"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

FeedFragment.kt

```
val extras = arguments
    extras?.putSerializable(ConstantsUtil.Extras.EXTRA_POSTS_MODE, PostsMode.GLOBAL)
    extras?.putBoolean(ConstantsUtil.Extras.EXTRA_BOTTOM_NAVIGATION_ACCESS, true)

    val navHostFragment = (childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_feed_content) as NavHostFragment)
    val navGraph = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.posts_navigation)
    navHostFragment.navController.setGraph(navGraph, extras)
```

ProfileFragment.KT

```
val extras = arguments
    extras?.putSerializable(ConstantsUtil.Extras.EXTRA_POSTS_MODE, PostsMode.MINE)
    extras?.putBoolean(ConstantsUtil.Extras.EXTRA_BOTTOM_NAVIGATION_ACCESS, true)

val navHostFragment = (childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_profile_content) as NavHostFragment)
    val navGraph = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.posts_navigation)
    navHostFragment.navController.setGraph(navGraph, extras)
```

Any suggestion on how to fix it or even what else could be happening so I can further investigate it is very much appreciated! Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem wasn't related to Android Navigation Component. I Also use Paging 3 and when I refresh the Posts fragment I delete all posts and add the first page of posts that I receive from backend. The problem was that when opening User Profile, I was refreshing the posts and that was making all posts to be deleted and only added the user posts into local database. Then when going back to Feed screen, the only posts in the database at that point are the ones from the selected user.

Problem fixed. Thank you all.